# Drag and Drop table columns using jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, html-table, drag-and-drop

I am having a table which has fixed header and first 3 columns are fixed .

http://jsfiddle.net/ncUdA/embedded/result/

I want to drag and drop the columns (i.e) A,B,C,D,E,F are columns which should be shiftable (drag and drop) enabled.All the elements below it should also be shifted to the new position.

http://jsfiddle.net/ncUdA/

I found a plugin which does what i want but  i was not able to implement because usage of multiple tables in my code for fixed header and fixed 3 columns.

http://johnny.github.com/jquery-sortable/#table

Below code is the plugin code on how to do it.

I am using handlebars for templating.

```
    var oldIndex
    $('.sorted_head tr').sortable({
      containerSelector: 'tr',
      itemSelector: 'th',
      placeholder: '<th class="placeholder"/>',
      vertical: false,
      onDragStart: function (item, group, _super) {
        oldIndex = item.index()
        item.appendTo(item.parent())
        _super(item)
      },
      onDrop: function  (item, container, _super) {
        var field,
        newIndex = item.index()

        if(newIndex != oldIndex)
          item.closest('table').find('tbody tr').each(function (i, row) {
            row = $(row)
            field = row.children().eq(oldIndex)
            if(newIndex)
              field.before(row.children()[newIndex])
            else
              row.prepend(field)
          })

        _super(item)
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

After google-ing to find the solution to re-order table columns by using drag'n'drop.
I found that 'akottr' has write an awesome jquery plugin. [here](http://akottr.github.io/dragtable/)

It is a library-independent js-function that gives you the ability to re-order table columns by using drag'n'drop. It's very easy to use.

```
$('#defaultTable').dragtable();
```

Thus, I hope you will get the re-order table as you want.
Check it out for more example : http://akottr.github.io/dragtable/

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for your suggestion. I just improved my answer by providing more detail. Sorry, I'm just a newbie here : )

Comment: @greg-449 could you please remove your down vote here. I got banned from your down vote. Thanks.

Comment: The downvote is not from me. There is no way to tell who downvoted.

Comment: @greg-449 I'm so sorry about that.

Comment: _library-independent js-function_ is a bit missleading, as it depends on jQuery and jQuery UI, the latter being the reason I am avoiding using it.